# Server Upgrade from CENT OS 4 to 6

Tags: centos, backup, upgrade

I will be updating my server since CENTOS 4.x is not supported long time ago. I really don't have any idea how to proceed and I have been searching how, but I can not understand since It is recommended to fresh install CentOS 6.x(latest), how can I backup my data? And what data should I'll backing up. Are my files gonna be deleted?

Comment: Yes, without a backup, your files will most likely be deleted if you perform a fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is always best to do a fresh install on empty partitions or otherwise you'll keep lots of unneeded files all over the place.  There is no magic solution to know where you saved your files.  They may be in `/home` but you could have saved then all over the place.

It may be a good idea to also backup the list of installed packages for future reference: `yum list installed`.

You should also backup your configuration files to more easily configure your new system but those will probably need to be updated to reflect the newer versions.  Since most are inside `/etc`, I usually backup it up entirely (for reference).

A full system backup could at least guarantee that you can later recover files that you forgot to backup.

Comment: Depending on how big of a filesystem you have, USB thumb drives are great backup targets and come in a pretty wide variety of sizes. As for what tools to use, the venerable `dump` command is still around, as well as other tools like `cpio`, `tar` and `rsync`. See their various manual pages for more information.